# Python strange list behavior

Tags: python, csv

i'm trying to update a csv file using the csv module but i've found some strange behaviour:

consider this code to read a csv

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('/Users/r2-d2/Desktop/output.csv', 'rb'), delimiter = '\t')
```

And printing this way

```
for row in reader:
    print row
```

This code totally works and i get multiple lists one of each represents a row of my cvs

Now consider this code:

```
for row in reader:
    print row[0]
```

This code does not work for reasons unknown to me. (IndexError: list index out of range) EDIT: row[0] is empty but any other index gives error even if non empty

This code however

```
for row in reader:
    print row[:3]
```

Works as expected and i get the first 3 entries for each row as a list.

I am definitely missing something.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the CSV files?

Comment: With the code that works, are any of the rows empty?

Comment: Yes some of the rows are empty but even non empty rows they throw

Comment: We need much more information. Please use [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clearer question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your rows must be empty.

```
my_list[0]
```

throws and `IndexError` when my_list is empty

`my_list[:3]` will never break, as it will try to give you the slice of data you want, but would return less if my_list is shorter than the last index requested.

try:

```
for row in reader:
    if row:  # identical to if(len(row))
        print row[0]
```

**EDIT:**

I think that you should try to open your file in standard mode, not in binary mode:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('/Users/r2-d2/Desktop/output.csv', 'r'), delimiter = '\t')
```

Comment: The first row is indeed empty but none of the other works e.g. 3 or 4 are not empty but still is error

Comment: can you show us the file content? Edit your question, please.

Comment: see my EDIT, it might help

Comment: @giudia: Once there is an error, execution halts.  Your program doesn't get a chance to look at lines 3 and 4 because there was an error at line 1.